# CakePHP How to create find conditions from multi level array?

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find, conditional-statements

I was wondering if there was a simple way to convert an array like this, which is passed from my form

```
Array
    (
        [Uk3] => Array
            (
                [code] => BOARD
            )
}
```

Info an array that can be used in a find, like this

```
Array
(
     [Uk3.code] => BOARD
)
```

Of course I wrote a loop to do it, but I would think there is helpful Cake method to do it.  Simple things like this can take an inordinate amount of time to figure out!

Thanks

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1502/format

Answer (score 1):

http://api.cakephp.org/class/set#method-Setflatten